# Zend Framework get the body html response from an action

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to get the body html response form a
controller action but with this code
$response = $this->getResponse();
Zend_Debug::dump($response->getBody());
I've got an empty string
so I'm wondering what's the problem :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing that in your controller, the body it's yet empty. If you want to get the response html of the body, you can use:

$this->view->layout()->disableLayout();

In your action. With that, you can get the response html as the response of your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But in that action in the view I've got the complete order (from the cart) and I need to get the html to build an pdf file so .....